# If there is a program that communicates to many different IPs on port 4000, how can I restrict that to just a few IPs?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have a program that communicates with other PCs as well as a central server to handle all of it on port 4000. What I want to do is make it so that the program doesn't communicate with all those different PCs, just 1 of them and the central server.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. Could someone help me with this? 
Thanks.

Comment: in theory this should be simple enough with a firewall rule that rejects inbound and outbound traffic that does not consist of the three IPs in question (your local IP, and the two remote systems). in practice, it can be a bit harder. it depends on the protocol (is it TCP port 4000? UDP?), what firewall package is installed (I am not at all familiar with Ubuntu anymore, I think it is called UFW these days), etc.

Comment: +0xSheepdog it's TCP port 4000, and yeah, the firewall is called UFW on Ubuntu, and that's the one I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good HowTo documents and guides online; I prefer the Digital Ocean tutorials myself and recommend them highly.

[How To Set Up a Firewall with UFW on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04)

There are some things you need to consider before diving into any sort of generic tutorial. Make sure you understand exactly what the program you are constraining is trying to do.

Understanding how a program initiates a session between your local machine and the remote server is important. You mention 4000/tcp: is this the port the server listens on? Does the server establish another connection back to your local computer on 4000/tcp? If yes, then you need to enable 4000/tcp both inbound and outbound to your only your trusted IPs. Why are other machines trying to connect to your local machine on 4000/tcp if it is not the server?

I would dig deeper into the application documentation and make sure you understand how and why all the different machines are trying to talk to the server and your local machine, if that is intentional or not, and what consequences blocking 4000/tcp to everything but the server and one other peer can have.

Comment: It's a P2P software that's why it communicates with other PCs. Basically everyone who installs the software forwards port 4000 or any port really, and it communicates with the bridge (central server) and other PCs. It's not just port 4000 if that changes anything. I'll look further into the networking, but basically this is how the program works: 1 PC sends a message, it gets handled by the bridge, and whoever has fast network speed + other factors gets the message. That sort of thing. Basically, I want the message to only be able to go to a PC I have set.

Comment: Okay, so if you don't want all those other "non-trusted" peers connecting to you, definitely make the firewall rule for incoming port 4000 restrict to just your two trusted remotes (server and the one peer you mention). Depending on the P2P app and the UFW capabilities, you may be able to restrict the applications outbound connections to the two trusted IPs on 4000/tcp as well. Lot's of details to work through, but this is the general overview. Should be doable. Good luck!

Comment: Ok thanks, you've been very helpful. I will try this and hopefully it works :)